# Why does "Enum" fail to compile when "enum" succeeds in c# .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, syntax-error, alias

Why does changing **enum** to **E**num cause compile errors?

Generally in c# one can use a c# type or its .NET equivalent.

Example:

```
string jeff = "Atwood";  // string type
String name = "Jeff";    // System.String
```

"[string (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)"
"
The **string** type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters.
 **string** is an alias for **String** in the .NET Framework."

The following .NET console application succeeds for "**enum**":

```
using System;

namespace UnhappyWithSystemEnum
{
    enum FirstEnum { Nothing = 0, Something = 666 };

    class CapitalE
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FirstEnum.Nothing);
            Console.WriteLine(FirstEnum.Something);
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Nothing
Something
Press ENTER to Exit
```

However, changing "**enum**" to "**E**num" causes multiple errors:

```
    Enum FirstEnum { Nothing = 0, Something = 666 };
```

error:

```
'invalid-global-code.FirstEnum':
    property or indexer must have at least one accessor
```

Please explain.

MSDN References:
"[Enum Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx)"
"[enum (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/sbbt4032.aspx)"

Comment: Well `enum` is not an alias for `System.Enum` the way the `string` is an alias for `System.String`. It is more like `delegate` which is used to declare a delegate type, but there is also `System.Delegate`. Keywords are not necessarily aliases for type names.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because **string** is an alias for **String**, but **enum** is not the same as **Enum**:

The **enum** keyword defines a new type that is inherited from **System.Enum** with members as static fields.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Member
}
```

is the equivalent (and I think it's actually the real generated CIL) of:

```
public class MyEnum : System.Enum
{
    public static int Member;
}
```

If you use **Enum** instead:

```
Enum MyEnum
{
     Member
}
```

would be like:

```
StringBuilder MyEnum
{
    Member
}
```

which obviously makes no sense for the compiler.

Comment: It is more like `public const MyEnum Member;`.

Comment: @PetSerAl roughly yes, but I think, unless you specify otherwise, it's: `public const int Member` as you can assing/read enum as integers. I'm actually having a look at the CIL code in a minute.